# Build error in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, build-error

I am pretty new to play framework and just trying to run a basic java-play app (hello-play-java).But whenever I try to build it ,It gives this error:-

```
error: object Project is not a member of package play
import play.Project._
        ^
Type error in expression
Failed to load project.`
```

My build.sbt file is as follows:-

```
import play.Project._

name := """hello-play-java"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.2", 
"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1")

playJavaSettings


fork in run := true
```

I tried googling it but didnt find much help.

Comment: What Play version is this? What's in your `plugins.sbt` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Play 2.3, you don't need that import.  This should work:

```
name := """hello-play-java"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.2", 
"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1")

fork in run := true
```

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/samples/java/eventsource-clock/build.sbt).

Comment: Ok..Will check!! Thanks.
BTW I did'nt change anything .I just imported the project and it's the default build.sbt file.So any reason for this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a project created with an older version of Play.  Check your project/plugins.sbt file - the version of the sbt-plugin will indicate which version of Play the project originated from.

Comment: Its 2.2.2.
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2").
I downloaded the activator 1.3.2 and dowloaded the latest project.

Comment: It would be a good idea, if possible in your organisation, to [migrate](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23) the project to Play 2.3.

Comment: Thanks..Will do for sure.
Isnt there any bundle with latest play framework?
Else for every project I need to modift the .sbt files.

Comment: Try this: [http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/2.2.6/play-2.2.6.zip](http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/2.2.6/play-2.2.6.zip) (taken from [here](https://playframework.com/download#older-versions))

Comment: Hi Steve.
I have come across 1 more doubt.
in the html file there is "href=/app"..But I cant get a reference to this html page.

Comment: Which html file?  Can you post it here (redacted if necessary)?

Comment: Its index.scala.html
     <html>
    <head>
        <title>play2-crud</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <ul>
    <li><a href="/app">CRUD index</a></li>
  </ul>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Check your routes file. /app will most likely be mapped to a controller method.

Comment: I found nothing as /app in routes file.
# Home page
GET     /               controllers.Application.index()
# CRUD Controllers and REST API
->     /                play.crud.Routes

.I downloaded play2-crud example

Comment: Since `/app` is hard-coded in index.scala.html, it looks like an error since it won't resolve to anything.  This is why route references should be used in place of hard-coded URLs. Alternatively, this is something fronted by a reverse proxy or similar, where `/app` is a valid URL which is provided outside of the Play app.

Comment: Yes..I also think so .But I am running it on my local server and it is working fine.So I am a bit confused.
This is the same project-https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud-activator

Comment: If you're running locally, you should be able to trace the call.  If you have a Global class defined, you can override onRequest and stick a breakpoint in there.  Without seeing the whole thing, it's hard to say anything more.

Comment: https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud-activator
You can see the project from this link

Comment: It's a route provided by play2-crud

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76000/discussion-between-steve-chaloner-and-mudit-agarwal).

Comment: Hi @Steve ..Can you help me in deploying play as war in windows using activator?

Comment: Nope, because I don't use WARs or Windows. This might help: https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin

Comment: Ok..Thanks..One more issue I am facing is,How to make a linux compatible dist from windows..It generates .bat files but I want .sh files